# How to enter 4 x 1 matrix in One Note Math Editor?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

How to enter 4 x 1 matrix in One Note Math Editor?

I don't see any appropriate visual option

[image]

and I don't see any non-visual options at all.

Answer (score 6):

Matrix `4x1` can be linearly represented with:

```
[\matrix (@@@)]
```

In general matrix `m x n` can be represented with `m-1` `@` and `n-1` `&`.

**EDIT**

Lots of office equation syntaxes can be found in this article:
[The Word 2007/2010 Equation Editor](http://www.iun.edu/~mathiho/useful/Equation%20Editor%20Shortcut%20Commands.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

You can add an existing matrix size similar to what you need, like the 3x1, then right click the inserted matrix and select linear.

This will give a simpler representation of that matrix, with at signs (@) signaling the start of rows and ampersands (&) signaling contents of a column/cell, which you can then try and add to by mimicking the style.

When I created a 3 row by 1 column matrix, this is what the linear format looks like:

```
■8(@@) -> ■8(@@@)
```

So I can just add another @ symbol to create another row to make it a 4x1 matrix. I am not entirely sure what characters the black box and 8 represent, but if you leave them, moving back to professional mode seems to work.

One you have turned the 3x1 matrix into a 4x1 matrix, right click it again and select professional. This should change it back to the more visual style you desire.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/equation-editor-matrices-in-word-2010/f31607e6-f49e-46eb-a176-97276e46a7cd